# Export list of pretty permalinks and post title

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Looking for a way to export a list of  pretty permalinks in WordPress with the corresponding post title. Looking for the actual permalink structure defined not the shortlink. I suppose if I have to, I will use a short link, but I prefer the full permalink.

Comment: Helps when we know the table(s) and columns involved - we don't all know the Wordpress data model

Comment: @OMG Ponies: If you don't know the WordPress data model you wouldn't be much help answering this question; the permalinks are not stored in the database directly. Thankfully we'll all have a new WordPress Answers from StackExchange go public within the week! When that happens it'll probably make sense to route people asking WordPress questions there as we'll have plenty of users on hand who know the WordPress data model intimately as well as all other aspects of WordPress!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: *Riight*... because I've *never* had to learn someone else's data model before & provide query optimization feedback.  If the questions were that prevalent, I'd have learnt the data model already.  But good luck with that!

Comment: @OMG Ponies: It's not learning the data model, is that to work with WordPress well you have to view it holistically integrating both database and framework knowledge. Expecting someone who doesn't know WordPress to give a good answer about how to best query WordPress just because they are a MySQL expert is like me expecting I could give a good answer on an Oracle PL/SQL question just because I have expertise in MySQL and MS-SQL. Knowing the platform matters.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: One more thing, most people asking these kind of questions about WordPress won't know the data model; in part that's why they are using WordPress as it generally keeps them from having to learn it. (No slight to you @jeff as it seems by your tagging of the question that you are aware of MySQl; I was speaking in generalities.)

Comment: Someone should should probably transfer this to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ if nobody has done so already.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a standalone PHP file you can save into the root of your website called something like `/export.php` and when you call it with your browser it will send a *tab-delimited plain text* list of posts with the pretty permalink, the post title and (as a bonus) the post type.

Just load the URL in your browser and then "*save as*" to a text file you can then load in Excel or however else you need to process it.

```
<?php

include "wp-load.php";

$posts = new WP_Query('post_type=any&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=publish');
$posts = $posts->posts;
/*
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT ID,post_type,post_title
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_status<>'auto-draft' AND post_type NOT IN ('revision','nav_menu_item')
");
*/

header('Content-type:text/plain');
foreach($posts as $post) {
    switch ($post->post_type) {
        case 'revision':
        case 'nav_menu_item':
            break;
        case 'page':
            $permalink = get_page_link($post->ID);
            break;
        case 'post':
            $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
            break;
        case 'attachment':
            $permalink = get_attachment_link($post->ID);
            break;
        default:
            $permalink = get_post_permalink($post->ID);
            break;
    }
    echo "\n{$post->post_type}\t{$permalink}\t{$post->post_title}";
}
```

Hope this helps.

-Mike

P.S. I used the standard WordPress `WP_Query()` but also included a commented-out SQL in case you prefer (or need) to use it instead.

Comment: Thanks MIke for the help and understanding.  I am getting a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 7 for some reason

Comment: Sorry, I made an unfortunate edit just before posting the code, doh! Fixed!

Comment: Thanks Mike,
Old post but still very effective snippet that just did the trick ;-)
Great!

Comment: Hi, this code is not working on the latest Wordrpress version. Please kindly fix. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

answered this one on EE this morning :)
http://wp.daveheavyindustries.com/2011/02/08/wordpress-permalink-via-sql/

this query should do it for you

```
SELECT  wpp.post_title,
        wpp.guid,
        wpp.post_date,
        CONCAT
        (
          wpo_su.option_value,
          REPLACE
          (
            REPLACE
            (
              REPLACE
              (
                REPLACE
                (
                  wpo.option_value, 
                  '%year%',
                  date_format(wpp.post_date,'%Y')
                ),
                '%monthnum%',
                date_format(wpp.post_date, '%m')
              ),
              '%day%',
              date_format(wpp.post_date, '%d')
            ),
            '%postname%', 
            wpp.post_name
          )
        ) AS permalink
  FROM wp_posts wpp
  JOIN wp_options wpo
    ON wpo.option_name = 'permalink_structure'
   AND wpo.blog_id = 0
  JOIN wp_options wpo_su
    ON wpo_su.option_name = 'siteurl'
   AND wpo_su.blog_id = wpo.blog_id
 WHERE wpp.post_type = 'post'
   AND wpp.post_status = 'publish'
 ORDER BY wpp.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted this solution and thanks @MikeSchinkle for the original solution. I did use this to export those links in plain text to excel and then build my redirect list.

But then I found that I also wanted a solution with live, active links.

So I used the `wp_query` using the post type "any" and created a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) with a search form included with the following query (customize to fit your theme as you see fit). Note I had to set the `posts_per_page` at -1 to return unlimited results.  This returns results as: "Title - Permalink"

```
<?php 
        $type = 'any';
        $args = array (
         'post_type' => $type,
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'order' => 'DESC',

        );
        $temp = $wp_query; // assign ordinal query to temp variable for later use  
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
            ?>

                <?php the_title(); ?> - <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="View The <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_permalink() ?></a><br />
<?php    endwhile; ?>
<?php else :
            echo '<h2>Sorry, we didnt find any results to match.  Please search again below or call us at 800-828-4228 and we will be happy to help!</h2>';
            get_search_form();
        endif;

  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

Hope that helps others.