# Wordpress permalink names are saved somewhere and I want to clear them out

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm taking over a wp site that was not completed.  All the pages that had been created were deleted.

I created a page and tried to rename its permalink to 'volunteer'.

However, I SUSPECT this page was once created because when I edit it and name it to /volunteer ... it automatically saves it as /volunteer-2 ?

IF I create a random named page ..i.e. testingPage, it will save the permalink like that just fine.

(My permalinks setting is set to: /%postname%/) ...

SO I am pretty sure there is a list somewhere of previously saved page names... can someone tell me where thats at and how I can clear it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the deleted posts deleted from the database or just placed in the WordPress "Trash"? When you save a post, it gets a unique "slug" which is used in the `%postname%` part of the URL. Posts that are in the "Trash" still exist in the database, so [the code picks it up](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2800). If you remove the old posts from the database, you can use the name again.

Answer (score 2):

Permalinks are not saved but dynamically generated depending on your settings.

The `%postname%` is a column called `post_name` in a table called `wp_posts`... in theory you could just change whatever is saved there BUT I suspect that this is dangerous!

For a query that gets the permalinks see http://wp.daveheavyindustries.com/2011/02/08/wordpress-permalink-via-sql/

Other information:

- [Export list of pretty permalinks and post title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464701/export-list-of-pretty-permalinks-and-post-title)
- http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/01/30/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/