# Get list of all permalinks n wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export list of pretty permalinks and post title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464701/export-list-of-pretty-permalinks-and-post-title)

I need to get a list of all the permalinks for my posts(about 8000) in an automated way(excel or csv) or atleast outputted in a normal format.

Any idea on how to do the same in the best way possible??

Comment: This was helpful.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464701/export-list-of-pretty-permalinks-and-post-title

Answer (score -1):

Use phpmyadmin http://www.phpmyadmin.net either via your webhost's install or your own and export the wp_posts table from the database in any output format you want, such as CVS , XML, etc.

Use the query `SELECT guid FROM wp_posts` and then export from that.

You may need to raise the php memory allocation for a large query like that.

Or limit the query, i.e. `SELECT guid FROM wp_posts LIMIT 0 , 1000`  at a time

Comment: just the guid is not what was needed... my comment above contains exactly what was needed...

Comment: This is not the public permalink.