# PHP script times out

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, timeout

I am using the script from this page: [Export list of pretty permalinks and post title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464701/export-list-of-pretty-permalinks-and-post-title)

it is for exporting list of wordpress posts and permalinks.
the problem I have is that I have over 2000 posts and the script does not get get executed.
On the other blog that has close to 1000 posts, this script works fine.
What php.ini setting or else needs to be modified?
The script stops loading after about 3 seconds.
I raised max_execution_time to higher, but it is not helping.

Comment: What do your logs say? 3 seconds doesn't sound like a timeout. Possibly hitting a memory limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the script execution time limit with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).
You can also raise the amount of allowed memory use for the script with something like this:
`ini_set('memory_limit','512M');`

Answer (score 1):

try this before starting the php code

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Att.

Answer (score 1):

Why you think it is about max_execution_time? Do you get error "Maximum execution time of 3 seconds exceeded"? Anyway you can set it:

1) in php `ini_set("max_execution_time", "60");`

2) in php 2nd way `set_time_limit(60);`

3) in htaccess: `php_value max_execution_time 60`

Answer (score 1):

If your script is using more than 512M or 60 sec on exporting 2000 Blog Posts, I recommend to check the code unless these posts have the size of a Phone Book each, really.